# GCC fails to vectorize a simple 2-level nested loop while Intel compiler succeeds

Tags: gcc, vectorization, icc

I have the following two versions of the same loop:

```
// version 1
for(int x = 0; x < size_x; ++x)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < size_y; ++y)
    {
        data[y*size_x + x] = value;
    }
}

// version 2
for(int y = 0; y < size_y; ++y)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < size_x; ++x)
    {
        data[y*size_x + x] = value;
    }
}
```

I compile the above codes using two compilers:

- Intel (17.0.1): I compile the code using: `icc -qopenmp -O3 -qopt-report main.cpp`. Both are vectorized successfully.
- GCC (5.1): I compile the code using: `g++ -fopenmp -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec -O3 main.cpp`. Only version 2 is vectorized.

Here are my questions:

- Why GCC fails to vectorize version 1? Is it because the inner loop in version 1 doesn't access contiguous memory?
- If the answer to the above is 'yes': is it for GCC impossible to vectorize it or it chooses not to because it won't have any performance benefit? If it is the latter, can I somehow force GCC to vectorize it no matter what?
- Apparently in version 1 the vectorization report of the Intel compiler includes these lines: `Loopnest Interchanged: ( 1 2 ) --> ( 2 1 )` and `PERMUTED LOOP WAS VECTORIZED`; while in version two I get this: `LOOP WAS VECTORIZED`. So it appears that Intel compiler rearranges the order of the loop in order to vectorize it? Do I understand this correct?
- Can I achieve something similar to the above with GCC?

EDIT 1:

Thanks to MarcGlisse I investigated further by creating a simplified example of my code and realized that different combination of my `data` size and compilation flags on GCC will achieve different vectorization. At this point I am more confused and I think it is better to create a new post to first understand how GCC vectorization works. In case someone is curious you can check the code below and try the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 for `size_x` and `size_y`. Also try them once with MarcGlisse's compilation flags and once without. Different combinations might give different vectorization results.

```
void foo1(int size_x, int size_y, float value, float* data)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < size_x; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < size_y; ++y)
        {
            data[y*size_x + x] = value;
        }
    }
}

void foo2(int size_x, int size_y, float value, float* data)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < size_y; ++y)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < size_x; ++x)
        {
            data[y*size_x + x] = value;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int size_x = 7;
    int size_y = 7;
    int size = size_x*size_y;
    float* data1 = new float[size];
    float* data2 = new float[size];

    foo1(size_x, size_y, 1, data1);
    foo2(size_x, size_y, 1, data2);

    delete [] data1;
    delete [] data2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve], we need to see the declarations of data, size_x and size_y...

Comment: Why `-fopenmp` when you don't have anything related here? Possibly relevant options: -march=native, -fvect-cost-model=unlimited and the graphite options (-floop-nest-optimize in particular, -floop-parallelize-all if you were hoping for some multithreading). If gcc/clang can't premute such simple loops, that might be worth reporting.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Turns out my problem is more complex than I thought. After your advice I wrote a simple code example to investigate further and edit my post. Turns out the size of  my `data` array would affect the vectorization. Also, the flags you suggested, some times help. And sometimes they will report that they vectorized a loop but the reported line would not belong to a loop but rather to the array element assignment.  My understang is that `main1.cpp:17:26: note: loop vectorized` means that it vectorized the loop at line 17.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: At this point I am quite confused and there is point editing this question because I first have to understand how the vectorization works on GCC. If I start to make any sense of my results I will create a new post. If you could write a proper answer mentioning the flags you suggested above I am willing to accept your answer because it motivated me to investigate further and gain a better understanding about that is going on. Thank you very much.